# How to compute the expected value of the ridge regression estimator?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, expected-value, regularization, bias, ridge-regression

I am trying to understand this derivation:

[image]

I think everything except the last equality is fairly simple, but I do not understand the last equality. Is there an error here?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no error.

Start with $X^\top X = (X^\top X+\lambda I) - \lambda I$; premultiply both sides by $(X^\top X+\lambda I)^{-1}$. Simplify.

Postmultiply by $\beta$